# JMeter (Beanshell sampler) Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 2, column 15. Encountered: "?"

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I'm passing XML from a variable into a string:

```
def request = '${variable}'
```

When I run my beanshell script, the response shows the following (note; line 1 is a comment):

```
Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 2, column 15.  Encountered: "?"
```

I believe it could be resolved by escaping the question mark (so "\\?" in stead of "?"), but I don't know how to do this in this specific example. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Your XML is broken and your script is faulty... what else could we say without seeing either?

Comment: @Gyro Gearless; Due to security reasons, I am not able to post the XML. ALso, this is the first step in the script, so the rest of the script is irrelevant (for now, at least). The XML is viable, cause it works perfectly in SoapUI, but I need it to work in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
String request = vars.get("variable").toString();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't do anything. I still get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Switch from Beanshell Sampler to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and make sure you choose `groovy` from the "Language" dropdown
2. Don't inline variables into "Script" are as it has negative impact to the overall script performance as it won't be compiled into the bytecode, so address the variable as:

   ```
   def request = vars.get("variable");
   ```

   `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides read/write access to all variables in scope of current Thread Group.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for Beanshell vs Groovy benchmark and scripting best practices.